# How to configure SSIS project to work with Subversion source control?

Tags: svn, locking, ssis

`I wonder how i could set up a developer enviroment for SSIS,.dtsx packages in Subversion?`

I read about Subversion "svn:needs-lock" property and the ability to set auto-props in a subversion repository by setting "enable-auto-props = yes" in the repository config file.

The "svn:needs-lock" property is neccesary when working with SSIS,dtsx to handle the files like binary files wich must be locked to avoid mergingconflicts.

`How should i configure Subversion config file for this kind of development?`

An example for setting auto-prop svn:needs-lock to .doc files (I think its working?!):

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.doc = svn:mime-type=application/msword;svn:needs-lock=*
```

Answer (score 0):

For a developer environment, do you need to check in any binary files?  Could you consider having only the source code files under source control and using SVN Ignore on the files or directories that have the binary files?  So any time a project or solution is built, the changes to binaries do not need to be committed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how development of SSIS,dtsx works but im responsible for setting up a Subversion enviroment that works flawless when developing SSIS,dtsx packages. I have read that its neccesary to work with Lock-Modify-Unlock instead of Copy-Modify-Merge solution in Subversion because .dtsx packages dosen´t merge changes good.